# Android: trying to create a custom dialog

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a custom dialog. When I call the `setOnClickListner` method I get a 
"the method setOnClickListner in the type view is not applicable for arguments." I also get a error on the line:

```
public void onClick(View v)
```

saying "The method onClick(View) of type new OnClickListener(){} must override or implement a supertype method". Code:

```
void ReStartsFamilyFriend()
{
    // custom dialog
    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.gameover);
    dialog.setTitle("Title...");

    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button


    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.butPlay);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog

        //on this line below get the error "The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments "
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        /*On the line below I get the error
        "The method onClick(View) of type new OnClickListener(){} must override or implement a supertype 
        method"*/
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Are you dismissing and then showing? Thats how it appears on here. Maybe just copy and paste the exact code how it is rather than explain it inbetween since it is a little ambiguous.

Comment: In the future please copy and paste your code exactly and do not try to add explanation in the middle of it. If you want to refer to a specific line add a comment on or above that line and mention it. The way you posted your code it was nearly impossible to tell what was happening with it, and it contained some seemingly erroneous brackets and parens. I tried to fix the formatting as best I could, but I reluctant to make a guess at a resolution because I have no way to be sure if I even understand the problem that you are facing. Does it say anything after "not applicable for arguments."?

Comment: Are you having compiler error? May be you haven't imported correct package!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like what you are trying to do is simply dismiss an alert using a different button other than one on the alert dialog.  Your best option would be to use VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVv

```
    dialog.setPositiveButton (CharSequence btnText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener{

    @Override
    onClick(DialogInterface dialogInter, int whichBtn){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    });
```

Theres no need to put a button in the view if you use an alertDialog.builder.
Check out the [link here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

Comment: Where dialog is the AlertBuilder that you established before this bit of code, but should definitely be an alertDialog.builder instead. Then when you are done putting options you can either directly use `dialog.show();` or you can use `dialog.create();` and it will make a alertdialog for you, and then you can show it. The former is easier so I recommend that